# How to add iterated objects into a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmutablearray

When I call DidSelectRowAtIndexPath, I'm checking to see if the cell was checked and if it is, check the key in Core Data.  (This process allows me to set the nav button from nil to Add if an item is checked). I also want to put the selected items in an array (or set) so I can call it in my Add method (to save to Core Data).  I've declared the checkedArray in the header file but it only saves the last selected cell into the array.  What is the proper way to do this?

```
Athlete *checkedAthlete = (Athlete *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[checkedAthlete setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:targetCustomCell.checked] forKey:@"athleteChecked"];

BOOL hasChecked = NO;
for (checkedAthlete in self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)
{
    BOOL isChecked = [[checkedAthlete valueForKey:@"athleteChecked"] boolValue];
    if (isChecked)
    {
        hasChecked = YES;

       checkedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:checkedAthlete,nil];
        //NSLog(@"%@",checkedArray);
    }
}
```

I also declared NSMutableSet in the header and tried:

```
  [testSet = [NSMutableSet set] addObject:checkedAthlete];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
checkedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:checked athlete,nil];
```

what you are doing is creating a new array with one item in it and assigning it to `checkedArray`.

What you want to do is create one array/set at and then add objects to it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.checkedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

and then later on you do

```
[self.checkedArray addObject:checkedAthlete];
```

This is taking the existing mutable array/set and adding a new object to it where as before you was creating a new mutable array/set each time with just the one item